# Value is not storing in sharedpreference in Android

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String status = jsonObject.getString("success");

                                        if (status.equals("1")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("UserDetail", 0).edit();
                                            editor.clear();
                                            editor.putString("mobile",edtmobilenumber.getText().toString());
                                            editor.commit();
                                            startActivity(i);
                                            finish();


                                        }
                                        else if(status.equals("0")){
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }


                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            pDailog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }) {
```

Comment: remove this ` editor.clear();`

Comment: done but it is of no use

Comment: what does editor.commit() return? commit() returns true if the save works, false otherwise.

Comment: where is your `context` initilized?..post the full code

Comment: Where are you trying to get your saved value from SP

Comment: after debugging the value comes is this is not available instead of mobile number

Comment: Post your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For saving the Shared Preference value as a String

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);



    public void saveValue(String key, String value) {       
        SharedPreferences.Editor saveValue = prefs.edit();
        saveValue.putString(key, value);
        saveValue.apply();
    }
```

For getting the stored value

```
 public String getValue(String key, String defaultValue) {           
        return prefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**FOR SAVING VALUES**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Hello");
editor.putInt("value", 12);
editor.commit();
```

**FOR FETCHING DATA BACK**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);

if (restoredText != null) {
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("value", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKS

Answer (score 0):

from documentation:

> Create a new Editor for these preferences, through which you can make modifications to the data in the preferences and atomically commit those changes back to the SharedPreferences object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following code :

First declare:

```
SharedPreferences myPreference;
```

In onCreate():

```
myPreference =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

In OnResponse():

```
myPreference.edit().putString("mobile",edtmobilenumber.getText().toString()).apply();
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the value? Please share the code.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, op's intention is to store data in preference, this answer should full-fill the needs.